# create instagram hashtag feed widget WITHOUT iframe

Tags: wordpress, api, instagram

I want to avoid using an iframe at all costs.

I know the alternative to using an iframe would be using instagram's API. After much research, though, I haven't been able to figure out the best method to create a hashtag feed that doesn't require me to spend multiple hours learning php, developing my own plugin, etc.

I'm able to find a lot of information ABOUT instagram API, but then I couldn't figure out how to actually USE it if that makes sense? *I don't know if I need to create a .php file and upload to my FTP, or if I need to create my own plugin or if should use the `wp__remote_get` function? All these methods are definitely over my head, but I'm willing to pursue one head on if I just know that I'd be spending my time reading the right stuff. So this is where I need some guidance from you.*

I have looked at the API documentation provided by instagram. I have "registered my client" and thus received my client ID and SECRET. After looking at the available endpoints, I think the one I want is the `GET` call ending with the following: `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` (see instagram documentation [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent))

If you're wondering why I don't want to use iframe, here is why:
1. it is not responsive and doesn't work well with my theme. In other words, it doesn't "behave" and seems to have a mind of its own
2. I've been told they are old news
3. they just drive me crazy

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the following jquery plugin which can easily be embedded into your page.
See the README.MD for a quick intro.

http://potomak.github.io/jquery-instagram/